# How do I fix syntax problems in my Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

Hello I'm using this code below to make python speak and say `hello world`.
I'm getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5haHu.png) when in want to run

Here's my code:

```
 import win32com.client as wincl
 speak = wincl.Dispatch("Sapi.spvoice")

 #start talk
 (print ("hello world")    
 speak.speak("hello world")
```

Comment: Is that exactly what you have in your py file? Even with the `>>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you go through the basics of `python`.

Your code above has `syntax issues`

However, to help you out make sure you have `win32com` as a `python-package` on your system.

Then run this:

```
import win32com.client as wincl
speak = wincl.Dispatch("Sapi.spvoice")

#start talk
print("hello world")    
speak.speak("hello world")
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if this helped you. Thanks!

Comment: thinks Alot ihave tried that in new IDEL worked!